# When does Android plans to bring icon notification?

Tags: applications, notifications

Moving from an iPhone to Android, I am surprised that Android does not have built in option to display app notifications (ex: number of unread email messages on the app icon).

I know there are many other apps and launcher which allow you to do this, but why isn't this built in yet?

Is this something that Android is planning to bring in future releases?

Comment: what android version and rom are you on?

Comment: Android has AppWidgets, which is much more flexible solution.